# Проблема с выводом данных с mongodb + node js+ express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

проблема состоит в одновременном выводом данных из mongodb.
Когда пытаюсь вывести данные на страничку всё выводиться, но есть еще один промежуточный обработчик который увеличивает значеные в бд  при загрузке страницы. Вот в этом и проблема как можно вывести одновременно и данные и что бы сработал запрос на бд на увеличение  значения. Я новичок в js.

````
  result.find({$or:  [{name:'police'} ,  {name:'score7'}]}, function(err, data){
      res.render('result_other', {result: data, title: 'Отчет из  Полиции'});
  });});



   <h4><%=title%></h4>
      <h3>
          <% result.forEach(function (result) { %>
          <%= result.text %> 
          <% }) %>
</h3>


  router.get('/result/police', function(req, res) {
  result.findOneAndUpdate({name:'score7'} ,{$inc:{text2:"11"}})});    


  

  <h3>
  <% result.forEach(function (result) { %>
  <%= result.text2 %> 
  <% }) %>

</h3> ```

Заранее спасибо.








вот этот код рендерит страницу и выводит в консоль текст, но не увеличивает значение в базе

  router.get('/police', function (req, res, next) {
  
  result.findOneAndUpdate({name:'score7'} ,{$inc:{text2:"11"}});
  console.log('123');
  next();
}, function (req, res) {
result.find({$or:  [{name:'police'} ,  {name:'score7'}]}, function(err, data){
      res.render('result_other', {result: data, title: 'Отчет из police'});
  });
});
````

Comment: уточните какие библиотеки используются, и в каком файле что.

Comment: используеться mongoose, express, вроде больше ничего. Вот еще пробывал так, но почемуто страница рендериться в консоль выводит данные, а  апдейт не срабативает.  router.get('/police', function (req, res, next) {
 
 result.findOneAndUpdate({name:'score7'} ,{$inc:{text2:"11"}});
 console.log('123');
 next();
}, function (req, res) {
  result.find({$or:  [{name:'police'} ,  {name:'score7'}]}, function(err, data){
   res.render('result_other', {result: data, title: 'Отчет из  police'});
  });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
router.get('/planet', async (req, res) => {
    ....
    const filter = { name: 'Luke Skywalker' }
    const update = { $inc : { visitCount : +1 } }
    const doc = await Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
    res.render('planet_report', {result: doc, title: 'Отчет'})
})
```

Смысл в том, чтобы использовать вариант с `await` перед вызовами функций, а не передачу колбэка.

Возможно нужен еще явный exec: `findOneAndUpdate(....).exec()`

Вообще действие (изменение) и последующее отображение лучше не перемешивать в одном  запросе с клиента. И еще `get` может кэшироваться, и расчитывать во время `get`-а что-то изменить не стоит.

Comment: а есть способ винести что то подобное на кнопку, что бы при нажатии увеличивало значение в бд? это было бы лучшим решение этой проблемы думаю.

Comment: конечно, на клиенте писать js и оттуда `button` `onClick` `fetch` `POST`. Или можно `form`-у сделать